# G Suite Admin SDK - get users list based on query with field schemaName.fieldName

Tags: python-2.7, google-api-client, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

I'm trying to get only users list based on a query.
According to the Google API client documentation for python, it will look something like this:
https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/documentation/admin/directory_v1/python/latest/admin_directory_v1.users.html#list

where `query=some_string`

I've tried getting users based on specific fields for example givenName
In that case, it would be `query=givenName:some_name`. This works!

However I would like to get a list of users based on the custom user attribute. According to the documentation, that would mean the field would be `schemaName.fieldName`
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users

However I've tried `query=schemaName.fieldName?SSO.role` but to no avail and I can't find specific examples for this field online.

How would the query look for this? My schemaName=SSO and fieldName=role

Thanks!

Comment: `query=SSO.role%3DroleName`, rember to use `projection=full` for that to work.

Comment: @Morfinismo: Thanks! I realized I was having issues because I was trying to use the key name and not the values.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by Morfinismo as a comment.